# How do I print 2 triangles with the front ends touching?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm tryng to make a triangle that looks like

```
*                 *
**               **
***             ***
****           ****
*****         *****
******       ******
*******     *******
********   ********
*******************
```

I have code that does this, but I'm unsure if my method is the correct way to accomplish this because I cannot use values less than 4 as my **n** parameter.

```
 public static void triangle(int n){   
    int shift = n*2 + 2;

    for(int row = 0; row <= n; row++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j <= (n*2)+(n/2); j++ ){
            if(j == 0 || j==shift){
                for(int i = 0; i <= row; i++){ 
                    System.out.print("*");
                    if(row == n && i == n)
                        System.out.print("*");

                }
            }

            if(row != n)
                System.out.print(' ');

        }
        shift-=2;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code with n=9 and it worked.

Comment: It does not work with 3 or 2

Comment: Your code seems a bit complicated & is hard to follow without comments.  To simplify I'd suggest keeping the outer loop for the number of rows and doing the work to print each row inside of there.  Consider each row will have 2n characters.  If the row number is called "row", print "row" stars, then (n - row) * 2 spaces, and then "row" stars again.

Comment: Thanks that made it way more sensible!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
public static void triangle(int n){ 
    int shift = n*2;
    for(int row = 1; row <= n; row++ ){
        for(int j = 0; j < row; j++ )
            System.out.print("*");
        shift-=2;
        for(int k = 0 ; k<shift; k++)
            System.out.print(" ");

        for(int j = 0; j < row; j++ )
            System.out.print("*");    
        System.out.println();
            }


    }
```